# STACKS: process_radtags only reads 1 input file and returns >90% barcode not found drops

Tags: genomics, demultiplexing, radseq

I am trying to demultiplex some paired-end ddradseq data and am running into an issue with STACKS in that the program only seems to read 1 of my files for input (there are 2) and also results in over 90% of my barcodes identified as not found, and therefore dropped. As a result, my retained reads are extremely low (1.1%). I ran this same script before on the same dataset and had good results so I am not sure why I am coming across this issue now?

The current script I am using is as follows:

```
module load stacks

process_radtags -p /home/heather/scratch/raw_inputs/ -P -o /home/heather/scratch/processrad_out \
 -b /home/heather/scratch/barcodes/lesp_barcodes_batch1.txt \
 -c -q -r --inline_inline --renz_1 sbfI --renz_2 mluCI
 
echo "Process radtags complete. Check log file to see dropped reads then proceed to alignment"
```

My input files are named HFL_R1_001.fastq.gz and HFL_R1_002.fastq.gz respectively (I have simplified these for the sake of this post, but the correct file names are specified in my scripts so this is not the issue). The program runs, but this is the output of the log file that I get which shows very low retained reads.

```
BEGIN per_file_raw_read_counts
File    Retained Reads  Low Quality     Barcode Not Found   RAD cutsite Not Found   Total
HFL_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz 11092204        3150    1029697796  12760620        1053553770
END per_file_raw_read_counts

BEGIN total_raw_read_counts
Total Sequences 1053553770
Barcode Not Found   1029697796  97.7%
Low Quality     3150    0.0%
RAD Cutsite Not Found   12760620        1.2%
Retained Reads  11092204        1.1%
END total_raw_read_counts
```

I have also tried running a script where I specified with the -1 and -2 flags which files I wanted the program to input specifically and get the same result, with the difference of the program seems to read data from both files, but still only finds the 1 input file:

```
Processing paired-end data.
Using Phred+33 encoding for quality scores.
Found 1 paired input file(s).
Searching for single and paired-end, inlined barcodes.
Loaded 191 barcodes (4-6bp / 6bp).
Will attempt to recover barcodes with at most 1 / 1 mismatches.
Processing file 1 of 1 [HFL_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz]
  Reading data from:
  /home/heather/scratch/raw_inputs/HFL_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz and
  /home/heather/scratch/raw_inputs/HFL_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

The rest of the log file from this particular script looks almost identical to the one described above, where retained reads are around 1%.

I have checked my barcode file and there are no unreadable characters and I can't imagine why I would be getting so many lost barcodes when this ran previously with no problem? If anyone has any insight it would be much appreciated. I am relatively new to bioinformatics and don't really know where to go from here.